# Count number of each different asset per site name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet where:
Column A is for site name (over 500 different names)
Column B has an asset type name (around 10 different asset names)

I want to be able to create a list of how many of each different asset there is per each different site.

There is anything from 0 to 50 of each different asset on each different site

Ideally set up in a table that when ever you make alterations to the main sheet this table auto populates or you can run a command to update:

| Site Name | Asset 1 | Asset 2 | Asset 3 | Asset 4 | etc etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 3 | 3 | 2 |  |
| B | 6 | 4 | 3 | 2 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is in `main1!A2:B500`.  Also Assume your summation table is on a different sheet and is laid out exactly as in your question, `“Site Name”` is in local cell `A1`.

`B2` will be:

```
=COUNTIFS(main!$A$2:$A$500,$A2,main!$B$2:$B$500,B$1)
```

Paying special attention to the $ signs.  Fill this formula down and across.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample about your requirement:

1. Use the **UNIQUE** function to get the Site Name Column automatically:

> =UNIQUE(A2:A18)

2. Use the ** SUMPRODUCT** function to get the count for each Asset type.

> =SUMPRODUCT(($D3=$A:$A)*(E$2=$B:$B))

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked so well, saves me counting manually all the time